# Que falhas de segurança foram encontradas no OAuth 2.0?

Tags: segurança, oauth, oauth2

Ontém li [esse texto](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/seguranca-de-dados/54190-cuidado-openid-e-oauth-estao-com-falhas-de-seguranca.htm) falando que foram encontradas falhas graves de segurança no OAuth. O teor do texto, em particular, faz parecer que não da pra usar o OAuth nem pensar. O problema com isso, é que estou desenvolvendo um projeto que o único modelo de autenticação e autorização plausível era o fornecido pelo OAuth.

Dessa forma, existem realmente falhas tão graves no OAuth como o texto afirma? Especificamente, quais são essas falhas que o texto se refere? Existe alguma forma de proteger contra elas?

Comment: Encontrei esse artigo, dê uma lida: [Serious security flaw in OAuth, OpenID discovered](http://tetraph.com/covert_redirect/oauth2_openid_covert_redirect.html)

Comment: Pelo que entendi, é algo que faz parte do OAuth, e cabe aos implementadores evitar o problema usando uma lista de domínios autorizados (*whitelist*). Ver http://it.slashdot.org/story/14/05/02/2015227/nasty-security-flaw-in-oauth-openid

Answer (score 2):

A falha não existe no protocolo mas sim na implementação de muitos servidores de OAuth.

O que se passa é que o protocolo OAuth redireciona o browser do usuário para a página de autorização do servidor, por exemplo o Facebook. Aí é passado um URL de retorno.

O Facebook pede permissão ao usuário para o aplicativo poder acessar a API do Facebook em nome do usuário. Depois que o usuário autoriza, o Facebook redirectiona para o URL de retorno.

Para evitar abusos do usuário ser redirecionado para um site não autorizado, o Facebook verifica se o URL de retorno é do domínio configurado para aquele aplicativo.

No entanto, existem situações de abuso que indicam como URL de retorno um de uma página que redireciona para outra que não é o do domínio tinha autorizado configurado, conseguindo assim burlar a verificação.

Quem tem de corrigir o problem é principalmente o servidor de OAuth, por exemplo Facebook, pois em alguns modos de uso do protocolo já retorna o token de autorização direto para a página de retorno sem uma devida verificação.

No entanto, se você tem um aplicativo que usa OAuth para acessar a API de outro site em nome de seus usuários, pode ser que alguém abuse do seu aplicativo para acessar contas do usuários no servidor de OAuth como se fosse o seu aplicativo.

Para evitar esse problema, evite ter páginas no seu site que redirecionem para sites arbitrários definidos como parâmetro no URL da página que redireciona.

O problema é mais complicado, mas esta é a versão simplista que acredito já dá para entender que precauções deve ter.